# Scheduled Job started, but no log entry found

Tags: schedulebatch

I have exactly the same configuration across 3 orgs - DEV, UAT and PROD.

I've got a few scheduled jobs that apparently started on the 06/11/2014 and one that started on the 01/11/2014 (Viewing Scheduled Jobs) in UAT:

[image]

Checking Apex Jobs view, I cannot see a log entry for any of these jobs. However if I manually execute one through execute anonymous, a log entry is created:

[image]

Looking at DEV and PROD, it looks like everything is working as expected:

[image]:

How come these jobs have "started" in UAT, but there aren't any signs that the jobs actually ran? I can guarantee that they did not run because some of them are sending emails out to the user and I haven't received an email upon completion. So no logs and the jobs did not run in UAT, but the "Scheduled Jobs" view says that they've started.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Is your email deliverability in the QA org set to "System Email Only"? That would stop the email from sending.

Comment: Nope it's set to all email.

Comment: Have any of the "Next Scheduled Run" date/times changed since the last screenshot now that the initial scheduled values have elapsed? E.g. has *Activate Accounts* changed from 7/11/2014 6:00 AM?

Comment: They all changed, Started today is "7/11/2014 6:00 AM" and Next Scheduled Run is "8/11/2014 6:00 AM". This is insane!

Comment: Anything to do with the way user emails are obfuscated when you refresh a sandbox ?

Comment: @Bachovski If the "Next Scheduled Run" dates are changing that would imply something is happening. Do you expect them to start batch jobs when run?

Comment: Correct, "Next Scheduled Run" is changing every day, but none of the batches are running at the "Next Scheduled Run". However if I execute one of them manually, they do run...

Comment: @Bachovski Maybe there is something preventing the scheduled job from starting the batch successfully? Can you increase the frequency of the scheduled job and capture a debug log when it runs? P.s. please use an @ reply so I get notified when you comment.

Comment: @DanielBallinger Re-scheduling the batches is going to fix this problem I think, let's see what happens. I'm trying to find the root cause of this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is the "answer" that I've got from Salesforce support (T3):

> Since those jobs were never made it to "Apex jobs" page (that being
>   said never en-queued and executed) we do not have job/Batch id's to
>   look in our server logs.
>
> Batch and scheduled are separate so something being in the scheduled
>   job page doesn't prove that a batch job had to have been en-queued.
>
> If this happens again do not delete the jobs from scheduled page.
>   Hopefully that would give some insights into the issue for R&D.

I've left the jobs on purpose so that they can investigate, but just before this "answer" I got another comment asking me to re-schedule the jobs :). Anyway, re-scheduling the jobs will fix the problem, though I'm still keen on finding out the root cause for this.